# How to check if two nested lists have the same structure?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I check if nested lists like these have the same structure:

```
list1={ { p[x],    p[y]    } , { p[x]    } , { p[x]   , p[y]   , p[z]   , d[z^2] } } 

list2={ { {1,2,0}, {3,0,0} } , { {0,0,0} } , { {1,0,1}, {0,1,0}, {1,1,1}, {0,0,1} } }
```

So I want to check, that there is a 3-tuple for each entry in list 1.

Comment: `Dimensions[list1]; Dimensions[list2]` says the dimensions is the same.

Comment: @Nasser But Dimensions returns {3} for each list. So if I add in `list1` a `p[z]` into the second sublist Dimensions still says they are equal.

Comment: You could compare `listN/. x_ /; Head[x] =!= List :> 0`

Comment: I actually do not understand the question. But if you want to look into each dimensions itself, you can do `Dimensions[list2[[1]]]` and so on. Mathematica sees each list as having 3 lists in it. But each list itself can also have other lists inside it.  and so on.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate or at least a version of an earlier one.  Can anyone recall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done reasonably quickly with `Position`. First, we get the positions of `p` or `d` within `list1`:

```
pos1 = Position[list1, _p | _d]
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}} *)
```

then we do the equivalent thing for `list2`:

```
pos2 = Position[list2, {_?NumericQ, _, _}]
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}} *)
```

A quick visual inspection reveals that the lists are the same, but they can easily be tested programmatically, too.

---

If you want a partial match, i.e. you wish to match `p` only, then `pos1` is only going to contain a subset of `pos2`, e.g.

```
pos3 = Position[list1, _p]
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}} *)
```

Then, to determine whether there is a triplet at these positions in `list2`, we use `Complement`

```
Complement[pos3, pos2]
(* {} *)
```

which returns all elements present in `pos3` not in `pos2`.

Comment: Could this be modified to allow for non numerical expressions in the 3-tuples? Basically my only concern is that all braces are correct. However, if this 3-tuple cotains {1,2,3} or {a,b,c} is irrelevant since I only want to check some obvious input errors by the user, if he later assigns a list to a I do not care.

Comment: @MrZ yes that's possible. I specialized it to numerical triples so that `Position` did not try to be overly inclusive, and that will be the ultimate issue with any pattern based system. But, this works as the triple pattern: `a : {_, _, _} /; AllTrue[a, FreeQ[#, List] &] `. However, I can imagine cases where it won't, so tweak it as needed.

Answer (score 2):

It could surely be done better:

```
list1 = {{p[x], p[y]}, {p[x]}, {p[x], p[y], p[z], d[z^2]}};

list2 = {{{1, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}};
Map[Dimensions, list1, Infinity] == Map[Dimensions, list2, Infinity]

(* False*)

p[_] := {a, a, a}
d[_] := {b, b, b}
Map[Dimensions, list1, Infinity] == Map[Dimensions, list2, Infinity]
(* True*)
```

Comment: But now p[x] will be interpreted as {a,a,a} in my entire notebook. Can this definition be done somewhat temporarily? `ClearAll[p]` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @MrZ You should use your own definitions for `p[x_]` and `d[x_]`.Mine were only examples

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility:

```
test[a_List, b_List] /; Length[a] === Length[b] := And @@ MapThread[test, {a, b}]
test[_p | _d, {_, _, _}] = True;
test[_, _] = False;
```

Now:

```
test[list1, list2]
```

> True

This has the advantage of (partial) early exit behavior unlike `Position` which will scan the entirety of both expressions even if the first term differs.

To improve the early-exit behavior here is a variation with [`AllTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html):

```
ClearAll[test]

test[a_, b_] := test[{a, b}]

test[{a_List, b_List}] /; Length[a] === Length[b] :=
   AllTrue[{a, b}\[Transpose], test]
test[{_p | _d, {_, _, _}}] = True;
test[{_, _}] = False;
```

Comment: While that works for user's data (and hence the +1), it doesn't work more generally. Try `list1a = {{p[x], p[y]}, {p[x]}, {p[x], {p[y]}, p[z], d[z^2]}}` and `list2a = {{{1, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {{0, 1, 0}}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}}`.

Comment: @rcollyer Are you referring to the code with `Inner` or the correction with `MapThread`?

Comment: `Inner`. I missed the correction which works well. Carry on. :P

Comment: @rcollyer I always appreciate the help checking my work.  I voted for yours too by the way.  I included an update that should be somewhat more efficient but it is not as clean as I would like.  I may return to this later.

Comment: Not an issue. I thought I had you, I was wrong. :D Truthfully, I was answering the user's question per the title, not just the text, and I was seeing if your's worked as well. I was surprised that you hadn't set it up so that it would work generally, and then I found out differently.

Answer (score 1):

Just for goofiness:

```
sameStruct[list1_, list2_] := 
  Quiet[MapAll[0 ## &, list1] /. Indeterminate -> 0] === 
   Quiet[MapAll[0 ## &, list2] /. Indeterminate -> 0];
```

Comment: When I try your method it returns false for the above lists.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one could use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html), which checks that the `List` structure of the second argument maps onto the structure of the first:

```
matchShapeQ[e1_, e2_] := Quiet@Check[
   Pick[e1, e2 /. Except[_List | List] -> True]; True,
   False,
   Pick::incomp]

matchShapeQ[list2, list1]
(*  True  *)
```

If a symmetric check is desired, then check both directions:

```
matchShapeQ[list2, list1] && matchShapeQ[list1, list2]
```

If matching a 3-tuple is required, perhaps

```
Quiet@Check[
  Pick[list2, list1 /. Except[_List | List] -> {#, #, #}, #] &@ Unique[]; True,
  False,
  Pick::incomp]
```

If the 3-tuples are to have three numeric entries, then it is not strictly a structural issue, but depends on matching the type of the entries.  `Pick` may not be a suitable tool in this localized case.

Comment: Doesn't your second method yield true even for this list2: `list2 = {{{1, 2, 0}, {3, c, 0}}, {{0, {0, 0}, 0}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 
    0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}}`

Comment: @MrZ Yes, because the sub-lists at the corresponding levels have three entries.

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing like this:

```
comp[n_] := 
 DeleteCases[list1, _, {n, -1}] === DeleteCases[list2, _, {n, -1}]
```

But you have to define the level at which you want to compare the similarity down to

```
comp[2]
(*True*)
```